# Changing the the_author_posts_link() hover title

Tags: customization, documentation

Is it possible to change the `title=""` attribute that Wordpress generates with `the_author_posts_link()` ?

It is currently displaying 'Messages of [User]' as a hover title but I wish to change this to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, but you'll have to use `get_author_posts_url()` (see [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url)).

The example in the Codex is (not my code):

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
```

You could add your own `title="My Better Title"` in that `<a>` tag to make it say whatever you like:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' ) ); ?>" title="My Better Title"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
```

Replace that with your text or anything you can generate. If you're getting text from somewhere else, be sure to wrap it in `esc_attr()` so it doesn't break your HTML.